Unable to send logs to Splunk using Java Logger and properties file
I am trying to integrate splunk into my project. For that, I am using the tutorial from: Splunk Website HEC
Currently, I have the following .properties file:
mySplunk.level = INFO
mySplunk.handlers =     com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLoggingHandler

# Configure the com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLoggingHandler
com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLoggingHandler.url = myUrl
com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLoggingHandler.level = INFO
com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLoggingHandler.token = myToken
com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLoggingHandler.source= mySource
com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLoggingHandler.disableCertificateValidation=true

Note: url and token are not put into this file but are available and the access is grated.
My SplunkTestLogger.java
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("mySplunk");
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C\\User\\myUser\\logging.properties");
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(fis);
    
        log.setLevel(LEVEL.INFO);
        log.addHandler(new java.util.logging.consoleHandler());
        log.setUseParentHandlers(false);

        log.info("starting myApp");
        fis.close();
  
      } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception occurred", e);
      }
    }
}

This class is not able to send any log messages to splunk. Why?
I already tried to connect and send events manually with
        URL url = new URL(SPLUNK_HEC_URL + "/services/collector/event");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Splunk " + SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        //....

and it was successful. but I want to make it work with the .properties approach.

Does it throw an exception (if so, what does the logger show)? Shouldn't the path have a colon i.e. C:\\User ?

No exception, only "Process finished with exit code 0". I don't understand your second question
